# Application design: Providing object metadata?

Tags: sql, performance, design-patterns, web-applications

This question might be quite broad, but I'm hoping for some answer that can push me in some direction.

Let's say I'm building an **event** calendar. The client fetches events from the server. Each event has a **date**, and after the date has passed, the event **status** is considered **done**. So there is some logic involved determining whether the event is done or not, in this example it's simple. Imagine that layer of logic being *much* more complex, where should the application execute this logic?

**Option 1 – Store in database**

So one option would be storing it in the database. The downside would of course be in keeping the data consistent and it would be necessary to use triggers to keep it up to date.

**Option 2 – Keep logic on server**

Every time the client requests the data, do the logic on the server and send it in response. The downside here is where the client would do many small writes to database so that the server would have to execute this logic every time, which could be quite intensive.

**Option 3 – Keep logic on client**

The client fetches the data and then does the logic. The downsides here is that the client requires all necessary data to do the logic, data it might not have. It also requires each client (web & apps) to implement its own logic when the data should really be platform agnostic.

Comment: option 2 seems the most logical. Just how complex can the business rules surrounding a calendar event get? Is it going to take several seconds to execute it or something?

Comment: Well I kind of have a 'tree'-type object, so the main `Event` object has a `status` and it has children and grandchildren. Small changes on grandchildren *could* affect the status of the main object. So the status depends on all children, so I'd imagine the logic could be costly

Comment: Realistically how many children / grandchildren is a real-life event likely to have? Recursion can be costly but not if you're only going a level or two down over a few nodes.

Comment: I would guess on maybe 1*7*5

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend that you keep your logic encapsulated inside a stored procedure or view which is called by server every-time it needs data. Operations will be fast on SQL side and there will be less payload.
This is most beneficial if you need **real time calculations**  but if you do need reasonable real time like check and change things every 15 minutes or so(depends on your event interval unit) you can cache results to be server at server level with an expiration date.
[image: Recommended arch solution]

If payload is not a problem **and logic is dependent heavily on user input** , you should do the calculations on optimized payload at the client side or server side.

Comment: Yeah I think that sounds reasonable. Perhaps one could add a check when updating children, if the status *could have* changed, and if so, run stored procedure. Time to dive deep into SQL then I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on performance, my suggestion is to keep in the server but to use a task runner to execute some feature in background each minute and load events from a cache or queue. Every new event should be published to a cache like redis that will free the database from many queries each time the routine verify the date of events to finish them just using the database for update data purposes. You also could use a Queue instead of Redis to keep the event in touch with the routine and pop him out when get finished. 
This routine could share the domain with the main application to avoid logic redundancy.